# IE 10 GPO not applying correctly until I reset IE settings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to configure security settings under the Local Intranet zone for IE 10 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I am also trying to add an IP address to the allow list for IE's popup blocker. I am configuring this under

User Configuration-> Policies-> Administrative Templates-> Windows Components-> Internet Explorer-> Popup allow list

User Configuration-> Policies-> Administrative Templates-> Windows Components-> Internet Explorer-> Internet Control Panel-> Security Page

When I first logon to the server and check the IE settings, none of them are working. The Security tab looks like this:

[image]

The only way I can get the security settings to apply is go to Advanced->Reset. After I do this, the policies are applied and the security tab looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I prevent this from happening? Also, the popup allow list never adds the IP address.

Comment: Is the user you are logging into actually getting the User GPO applied to their account?  Are they in the right OU?

Comment: Run `gpupdate /force` and `rsop.msc` to make sure it's being applied. GPOs change the registry settings, which may not take effect until you close IE (all processes) or even restart the computer. I can't check right now though.

Comment: Have you customized the default user profile at all? This looks like the default profile is all munged-up.

Comment: Once I reset IE's settings, the user is getting the IE GPO. I have not customized the default user profile. It looks like the browser is extremely locked down and then the GPO applies. The GPO may be applying, but I cannot check any of the settings because everything is locked.

Comment: Apparently it was some rogue policy in my original Group Policy. I recreated the group policy and everything seems to be working now.

Comment: I will go through and enable each policy individually until I can find the one that was causing the issue. I did have "Prevent first run wizard enabled". This may have been causing the problem.